# Xcode 5 is messing up my views

Tags: ios, xcode5

I started building an app using xcode 4. Recently, I updated xcode4 to xcode 5 and xcode 5 updated my storyboards and xibs. Since there is now translucent status bar, all by views are moved twenty pixels up, but xcode says 4 of my views are vertically ambigous. The image i used for the background is now too short heightwise. I made it longer, but xcode gives me the error saying the image is different at runtime. So how can i fix my storyboards and my view so it looks as it did on xcode 4 and ios 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend first going through all of your viewcontrollers, selecting them, and tapping in the lower right corner of the storyboard, middle panel, one icon from the right "resolve auto-layout issues" and try reseting the autolayout for the storyboards.

Beyond that, you should familiarize yourself with autolayout.  You should check out the [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) tutorial to get you started.